# How get all cache_directory of baked files?

Tags: python, cache

[image]

I need to get list of cache_directories for every object.
Now i use that

```
pathes = []
for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    for modifier in obj.modifiers:
        if hasattr(modifier, 'domain_settings') and modifier.domain_settings is not None:
            pathes.append(modifier.domain_settings.cache_directory)
```

Is better way to get all these pathes ?

Comment: you have a 5 lines coding solution and you are searching for a even better one....!? wow...that's ambitious...! :D

Comment: The only thing you could do to improve that would give you a small performance gain at the cost of readability: Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) instead of the nested for loop.